# Why won't this loop increment a variable?

Tags: c#, loops

I am trying to do a calculation which involves a do while loop in c#

- I want to execute the loop and minus the quantum from the remainingTime array and assign the new value to timeelapsed.
- My loop should execute while timeelapsed is > 0 and stop once it hits 0

However, the loop does not carry out the - quantum part of the code, i don't understand why.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         int quantum, noOfProcesses, processNumber = 0; // noOfprocesses variable is to determine array sizes, processNumber tells user what process number they input
         int timeelapsed, count = 0;

         Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of processes:");

         noOfProcesses = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // allows numerical input 
         int[] bursttime = new int[noOfProcesses];
         int[] arrivalTime = new int[noOfProcesses];
         int[] remainingTime = new int[noOfProcesses];

         for (int i = 0; i < noOfProcesses; i++)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Enter Burst time for process #" + processNumber);
             bursttime[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
             processNumber++;     
         }

         processNumber = 1; // resets the process number for user interface 

         for (int i = 0; i < noOfProcesses; i++)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Enter arrival time for process #" + processNumber);
             arrivalTime[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
             processNumber++;
         }

         Console.WriteLine("Enter the time quantum:");
         quantum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // allows numerical input

        // calculations

        processNumber = 0;


        if (count <= noOfProcesses)
        {
            // remainingTime[0] = bursttime[0] + arrivalTime[0]; // burst + arrival = remaining time

            for (int i = 0; i < noOfProcesses; i++)
            {         
                do
                {
                    remainingTime[i] = bursttime[i] + arrivalTime[i]; // burst + arrival = remaining time
                    timeelapsed = remainingTime[i] - quantum; // - the quantum gives whats remaining
                    timeelapsed = timeelapsed - quantum;  
                }
                while (timeelapsed > 0);

                Console.WriteLine("#" + processNumber + " Time taken: " + timeelapsed + "ms");
                processNumber++;
                count++;
                //timeelapsed = bursttime[i] + arrivalTime[i];

            }
        }

       // Console.WriteLine(arrivalTime[j]);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
```

Please note that the noOfProcesses and processNumber variables are defined in the program i don't believe these are causing the issue.

Comment: You are in the best position to discover the problem. You have the data, you have the code, Do you have a debugger?

Comment: Is quantum also defined elsewhere?

Comment: even if you don't think they are causing the issue including the code where these variables are defined could be helpful so we can see the full picture.

Comment: The quantum variable is defined at the start of the program and is assigned a value from the user input. I am trying to debug the code, I see that the quantum variable is getting a value passed to it and timeelapsed is also getting a variable but the calculation is not being carried out.

Comment: I have now updated the question with the full code, apologies for not including the whole thing to begin with.

Comment: Also without a debugger I see that your do..while is an infinite loop unless the quantum variable is bigger than the sum of the burst and arrival time. This happens because in that loop you first make the sum of the two times, then subtract the quantum and then repeat the loop making again the sum of the two times. You will never exit from that loop. In any case, also if you were able to exit, the timelapsed variable is always zero so your result is meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, i see your point. I am working on a solution.

Answer (score 2):

All you are doing in this loop is recalculating the same values over and over again:

```
do {
   remainingTime[i] = bursttime[i] + arrivalTime[i]; // burst + arrival = remaining time
   timeelapsed = remainingTime[i] - quantum; // - the quantum gives whats remaining
   timeelapsed = timeelapsed - quantum;  
} while (timeelapsed > 0);
```

For example, you might see this if you use real numbers:

```
do {
   remainingTime = 100 + 100;
   timeelapsed = 200 - 10
   timeelapsed = 190 - 10;
} while (timeelapsed > 0);
```

The loop never ends. I'm not sure exactly what your goal is, but you probably need to keep a running total, like:

```
remainingTime[i] += bursttime[i] + arrivalTime[i];
```

Or

```
remainingTime[i] -= bursttime[i] + arrivalTime[i];
```

Comment: I'm trying to loop through until the timeelapsed variable is 0 or less. Then i want to move to the next position in the array using the variable "i" and repeat this until i reach the end of the array.

Comment: For clarity, the user is entering the values of the bursttime and arrivaltime and those values are saved into the array. Then the calculations are carried out for each array position and presented to the user at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is really debugging and tough to decide without having the code in front of me. I'm assuming that the 'quantum' code is the section in the `do` part of the loop. In which case, the only reason why it isn't running is one of the three:

1. `noOfProcesses` is less than 1
2. `timeelapsed` is <= 0
3. It is getting to the first iteration of the loop but an exception is being thrown.

Since you're using c#, and hopefully VS, you should use the debugger and step through your program.

Comment: I don't understand why this was down-voted. I was truly trying to help the OP out since it is obvious he is a beginner. The answer is correct...

Comment: I'm not sure either why you were down voted, i appreciate your help, i have updated the question with my code now.